# Uri' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: flutter, dart

**bin/dart_application_1.dart:18:74: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.  - 'Uri' is from 'dart:core'.       await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/$userId");**

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  fetchUserId();
}

void fetchUserId() async {
  print('before');
  var result = await fetchUser(5);
}

// future
Future<Map<String, String>> fetchUser(int userId) async {
  // return Future.delayed(
  //     Duration(seconds: 5), () => {'id': userId.toString(), 'name': 'Max'});
  var responce =
      await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/$userId');
  var map = json.decode(responce.body) as Map;
  return {'id': map['id'].toString(), 'name': map['name']};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  fetchUserId();
}

void fetchUserId() async {
  print('before');
  var result = await fetchUser(5);
}

// future
Future<Map<String, String>> fetchUser(int userId) async {
  // return Future.delayed(
  //     Duration(seconds: 5), () => {'id': userId.toString(), 'name': 'Max'});
  var responce =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/$userId'));
  var map = json.decode(responce.body) as Map;
  return {'id': map['id'].toString(), 'name': map['name']};
}
```